# Overlay inconsistency with tabs

Tags: workflows, modal-dialogs

I just enabled and configureda workflow module. The edit, outline and revisions tabs display in an overlay state whereas the workflow goes out of the overlay and to the site, if that makes sense.

Why is this happening? Where do I change the settings for this so all the tabs behave the same?